# Where does PUTTY stores its Sessions?

Tags: putty

Looks like somewhere in Registry.

Tried to launch different exec files - sessions are the same.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions

Comment: Thanks for tip, this answer was useful to help sleske : http://serverfault.com/a/745968/329412

Answer (score 11):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY in SshHostKeys or sessions