# Different SSH ports/keys for different hosts, with TortoisePLink

Tags: ssh, mercurial, putty, tortoisehg

TortoiseHg (Mercurial) normally uses TortoisePLink/plink to connect via SSH. Different SSH hosts have different settings, including private keys and ports to connect to.

In its global `hgrc` settings, TortoiseHg lets you specify different logins and passwords for different hosts, but not private keys nor ports.

How to override SSH port/private key globally, but only for some hosts and not others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll list a number of imperfect approaches for completeness, then give the one I've found that I think is better:

###### ssh setting

Mercurial `ssh` setting can be used to pass additional params to plink globally:

```
ssh=path\to\TortoisePLink.exe -i "private1.key" -i "private2.key" -P port
```

But the same `ssh` string is used for all hosts, so different ports cannot be configured. And while you can list several private keys, some servers will refuse all but the first one.

###### putty's saved sessions

plink comes from putty package, and putty can store server configurations (sessions) [in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012700/where-does-putty-stores-its-sessions), `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions`. plink can use these if you use a session name in the host place, e.g. `ssh://session-name/path/to/repository`.

But for some reason [plink ignores stored port settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867564/plink-proxy-error-connection-refused-while-putty-works-with-the-same-session) and will use the default SSH port. Probably a bug, but it's unfixed.

###### Local hgrcs

You can override `ssh` for each repository by creating a local `.hgrc` file, but it's unwieldy if you have lots of repos.

- You have to remember to do this every time
- Cannot just "clone repo from address"
- What if your repo can be synced to two different servers?
- What if one of the servers changes its SSH port, you'll have to find and update every repo everywhere.

###### Explicit ports

You can specify ports explicitly in the remote repository address:

```
ssh://server.name:port/path/to/repository
```

Same problems as with local hgrcs.

###### PLink script wrapper

After struggling with this for a while, I have finally thought of something that seems to work. We can wrap TortoisePLink in a script that adds per-server params:

```
ssh=path\to\TortoisePLinkWrapper.cmd <all the normal common params>
```

Create a file called `username@host.name.cfg` for every host you want to override, and its contents should be additional params to pass to TortoisePLink, e.g.:

```
-P 1234 -i "path\to\key.file"
```

Place this in the same dir:

```
@echo off
set SERVER_PARAMS=
set SERVER_NAME=
call :find_server %*
if "%SERVER_NAME%"=="" goto :call_plink
set "SERVER_CONFIG_FILE=%~dp0%SERVER_NAME%.cfg"
if NOT EXIST "%SERVER_CONFIG_FILE%" goto :call_plink
set /p SERVER_PARAMS=<"%SERVER_CONFIG_FILE%"

:call_plink
rem TortoisePLink ignores some params if you pass them after the ssh command, so add extra commands before the bulk of them
"%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePLink.exe" %SERVER_PARAMS% %*
exit /B

:find_server
if [%1]==[] exit /B
rem Known arguments which eat some more positions
rem https://putty.org.ru/htmldoc/chapter7.html
if [%1]==[-P] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-l] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-pw] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-proxycmd] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-sercfg] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-D] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-L] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-R] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-i] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-hostkey] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-m] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-nc] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-sshlog] shift & shift & goto :find_server
if [%1]==[-sshrawlog] shift & shift & goto :find_server
set "PARAM=%~1"
rem Other flag argument:
if "%PARAM:~0,1%"=="-" shift & goto :find_server
rem First positional argument
set "SERVER_NAME=%~1"
exit /B
```